# Data about writing as a hobby

Tags: data-request, books, literature

I'm looking for information about what percentage of the population (in any Western country) write (literature) as a hobby. Either in the present day, or in historical development.

Comment: Changed tag *population* to *books*, that's closer. And maybe the new tag *literature* holds

Comment: i would think nanowrimo or however you spell the month writing competition would have this data